# Python error when launching gnome-tweak-tool on Debian

Tags: gnome, python, debian, gnome-tweak-tool

When trying to launch gnome-tweak-tool I recieve this error

```
~ gnome-tweak-tool
gnome-tweak-tool\Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/app.py", line 39, in do_activate
    self.win = Window(self, model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 46, in __init__
    titlebar = self.titlebar()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 81, in titlebar
    self._update_decorations (Gtk.Settings.get_default(), None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 196, in _update_decorations
    self._right_header.props.decoration_layout = ":" + tokens[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas on how to successfully launch gnome-tweak-tool?

Comment: Questions on Debian should be asked on [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/65604/gnome-tweak-tool-crashes-when-executing/) might be useful :

> Go to /usr/lib/python2.7/**dist-packages**/gtweak/tweakview.py & find the line,
>   that generated an error: self._right_header.props.decoration_layout =
>   ":" + tokens[1]
>
> One line before that there should be if tokens != None: Change that to
>   if not tokens:
>
> The first one doesn't account for tokens being empty, which, for some
>   reason, is the case. Hope that helped.